# git command to get all branches I've merged into develop since a given date?

Tags: git

I need to provide a list of all branches I've merged into develop since a given date.  Can you recommend a git command that will do this?

Comment: Here is a possible method to test if branch A *so far* has been *fully* merged into branch B, `git branch --contains A`. If the output includes branch B, A has been fully merged into B. But the "since a given date" part is a trap.

Answer (score 1):

In general, git doesn't keep information about which branches are merged into another branch, assuming you deleted the branches in question from the machine.

There might however be a way to produce the list you need if you used the default merging method: actually merging instead of re-basing, fast-forward merges or squash merges. In this case you can get a list of the automatically generated merge commits using the following commands:

```
git log --oneline REV... | grep "Merge branch"
```

In this command `REV` is the revision from which you start the count. As you probably can see, this command uses all revisions in the time period and filters them using `grep`, using to the text that's used for automatic merge commits. The result will be something like:

```
b527bad Merge branch 'BRANCH' of bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx
9b13c8d Merge branch 'OTHER_BRANCH' of https://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx
925495d Merge branch 'master' of github.com:xxx/xxx
03e9f43 Merge branch 'develop' of privateparty123.com/xxx/xxx
```